# Repeated "Connect to iTunes to Use Push Notifications" prompts?

Tags: iphone

I just backed up my iPhone 4S and restored it onto my iPhone 5. Now, whenever I open "Find My Friends", I get a continuous stream of these messages:

> Connect to iTunes to Use Push Notifications
>
> "Find Friends" Notifications may include alerts, sounds and icon badges.

I can't actually do anything else with the app because as soon as I dismiss one message, another (identical) one pops up. I tried deleting and re-downloading the "Find My Friends" app, but I get the same result.

According to [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3394511?start=30&tstart=0), I can fix the problem by doing a backup and restore onto my phone, but I'd rather not if I can help it. Is there another way to fix this?

Comment: Just curious, have you gone to Notification settings and turned off FMF notifications (completely - everything) to see if the app at least becomes usable?

Comment: Yep, turned it all off. Doesn't make a difference. :(

Comment: Weird. Especially because I didn't think you *needed* iTunes to receive Push Notifications (in fact, I *know* you don't). I don't think it would fix it but reboot your phone just to make sure. Only other thing I can think of would be sign out and back into iCloud, but that may delete some Photostreamed pictures from your devices - not sure on that one. Otherwise, you may be stuck with a restore. Course, with iCloud it is at least easier then iTunes.

Answer (score 2):

I had to work this out because it was happening to me to but with the snapchat and facebook messager app. All you need todo is reboot your phone and reset your network settings then after that sign back into your wifi or just use 3G. I'm sure if you tried it would work with any app.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me, and no need to restore the device.

Answer (score 1):

If you are jailbroken, install SAM. Once installed, go to your iPhone Settings > SAM > Utilities and run De-Activate iPhone (Clear push).

Restart your phone and connect to iTunes. Problem should be solved.

Comment: First confirm that he *is* jailbroken before you write an answer that does not address non-jailbroken iPhones.

Comment: @sam It's fine to provide answers for jailbroken devices, even if the OP has not stated if their device is jailbroken, as this may help other users with their problem who may have a device which is jailbroken.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up backing up my iPhone, wiping it, then restoring the backup onto it. After that, everything worked fine. There might be a better way of doing it out there, but if so I didn't find it...

Answer (score 0):

You have to just log off from itunes&app store, reboot and then log on agsin. Had the exact same problem with Dropbox and this loop of popups to connect to itunes etc. Doing the above fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I simply went into the settings and went into the app's settings, then after that I turned off location services and background app refresh for the app and then it worked just fine! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I tried rebooting, logging out and in App Store, and none worked. It's the Music app that's causing the trouble. Log out of your Apple ID in the Music app and log back in. It'll fix the problem; at least it did so, for me. And my issue was with more than one app. All notifications were messed up.